# Linux Path environment variable -- add path with spaces in the right way

Tags: python, linux, path, environment-variables, space

I want to append a path to my PATH environment variable under Linux. I do it temporarily in my Python program (by setting `os.environ['PATH']`) and I want it to be done reliably. In particular, I worry about the case when the path contains spaces. I tried to add such a path to PATH variable in four ways:

- just to append the path with spaces as it is:     `/a b c:/usr/bin`
- to append the path with spaces in double quotes:  `"/a b c":/usr/bin`
- to append the path with spaces in single quotes:  `'/a b c':/usr/bin`
- to append the path with spaces escaped with ' \ ':  `/a\ b\ c:/usr/bin`

So for me only the first, the simplest way, worked. For all the others, my executable is not found. It's a bit unexpected, as I was sure that I should always be aware of paths with spaces and process them in some way. Is this behavior reliable? Or can it break and there is some other way to add paths with spaces to PATH properly?

Thank you for attention! I really searched on the Internet but I failed to find this information except for this link: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94679/how-do-cope-with-a-space-when-setting-the-path. But here it is about how to *add* the path to PATH and not about if it is okay to have it without any quotes or backslashes or something else there.

Comment: Spaces have no special meaning in the `PATH` variable, they don't need to be quoted or escaped.

Comment: @Barmar, thank you for the comment! Do you know, by chance, where I can find this information? Or is it kinda a common knowledge? Just really cannot find it.

Comment: Backslash and quotes will be treated literally in the `PATH` variable, do not add them. The only character that has any special meaning is `:`, but I don't think there's any way to escape it.

Comment: It's stated by omission. The description of the `PATH` variable doesn't say anything about needing to escape things, so don't. It's just a sequence of pathnames separated by `:`.

Comment: @Barmar, ah, I see. Thank you again!

Comment: Spaces are an issue when you're setting the variable in a shell script, because spaces have meaning to the shell. You'd have the same issue with any other variable, it's nothing about the value of `PATH` itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement of escaping spaces in PATH environment variable since it has no special meaning there.
So, if you are appending a path to the PATH environment variable, you can totally ignore the presence of spaces in that path.

Code:

```
import os

path_to_add = '/home/user/My Path'  # A path with space

print(os.environ['PATH'])  # Prints /usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin

os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + path_to_add
print(os.environ['PATH'])  # Prints /usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/user/My Path
```